# Java: measuring performance of an application by upgrading it to a web service

Tags: java, web-services, performance, monitoring

I have an application that's behaving as a server in a way. I have some consumers (another application) which send tasks to the "server" application and get something as a result. The application is implemented in Java as a console application. The problem is that I need to measure the performance of the application (CPU, memory, throughput if possible and anything else I could get). If I keep my "server" as a console application, I get a problem of application level measuring, which can be extremely hard. My idea was to "upgrade" the console application to a web service, i.e., to create some kind of a wrapper so to be able to call the "server" as a web application. I guess that the monitoring part would be much easier then.

I'd like to hear your thoughts about it. Is that a good idea? Can I get better results if I upgrade it to a web service? And how do I even do that? At this point I just want to get some results, the code can be dirty. The application is originally imagined as a web service (or something similar), the console application is just a simulation, so creating a web service instead of a console application is not a terrible thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use JMX protocol and JConsole to connect to your application. With  JConsole you will have detailed information about memory usage, CPU usage, threads etc. It will also allow you to control your application on the fly by means of MBean.

Take a look at: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html

Comment: @Op. We are using JMX to monitor our server processes/applications. Works great, and there are html adapters that can be used with JMX. I don't see a point in switching to a web service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its a good idea to make your application a Web Service. It will make your application secure and scalable out of the box.

You can chose yourself that which web service you want to apply. I would suggest you to go for RestFul web service (JAX-RS). And you can use sl4j for logging all the information about the mem and cpu usage.

Comment: "It will make your application secure and scalable out of the box." - care to expand on this?

Comment: All the web services provide their own ways to secure the application. So instead of securing your own application via custom build security it would be a good idea to use that. For scalability, you do not have to manage that how many users are using application right now. All the requests will be handled by the web services in their respective sessions.

Comment: OK, so by 'scalable' you mean 'handles concurrent requests'. I understand now!